# Extract one number from string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this string:

```
1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)
```

and I need to get only the number `912.48` and transform it in `912,48` with a bash script.
I tried to do `sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'` but in this way i get `1024.00 912.18`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `awk` and `sed`:

```
str='1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)'
echo "$str" | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/(//;s/\./,/'

912,48
```

Or entirely with `awk`:

`echo "$str" | awk '{sub("[(]","");sub("[.]",",");print $4}'`

Answer (score 2):

So far, every answer here is using external tools (`sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `tr`, etc) rather than sticking to native bash functionality. Since spinning up external processes has a significant constant-time performance impact, it's generally undesirable when only processing a single line of content (for long streams of content, an external tool will often be more efficient).

This one uses built-ins only:

```
# one-time setup: set the regex
re='[(]([0-9.]+) MB/sec[)]'
string='1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)'

if [[ $string =~ $re ]]; then  # run enclosed code only if regex matches
  val=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}       # refer to first (and only) match group
  val_with_comma=${val//./,}   # replace "." with "," in that group
  echo "${val_with_comma}"     # ...and emit our output
fi
```

...yielding:

```
912,48
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\(([0-9.]+).*/\1/;s/\./,/'
```

Comment: I'd use `/^.*\(([0-9.]+).*$/` for extra paranoia, but YMMV.

Comment: sed: 1: "/^.*\(([0-9.]+).*$/": RE error: parentheses not balanced

Comment: @SegFault you omitted the backslash before the first left parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)" | cut -f2 -d'(' | cut -f1 -d' ' | sed 's/\./,/'
```

Comment: if you're avoiding `sed`, go all the way and change to  `tr '.' ','` as well.

Comment: @karakfa, I wasn't trying to avoid sed.  Just using a different approach.  Thanks for the "tr" suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)" | cut -d " " -f4 | tr "." "," | tr -d "("
```

Answer (score 0):

Another of the near-infinite possibilities:

```
read x y < <(tr -dc '[0-9. ]' <<< "1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)")
echo ${y}
```

or

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()[\d.]+' <<< "1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` to get the job done:

```
s='1024.00 MB transferred (912.48 MB/sec)'
awk -F '[() ]+' '{sub(/\./, ",", $4); print $4}' <<< "$s"

912,48
```

Answer (score 0):

wow, so many answers :)

here's mine, should be pretty fast:

```
grep -o '([^ ]\+' | tail -c+2 | tr '.' ','
```